# Which design approach to reduce code duplication

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, soap

I am trying to write code to invoke external services using java Httpurlconnection and noticed code is getting duplicated , but I am confused now whether to duplicate code or use lots of if-else block and write everything in single place.

Following are scenarios or type of services needs to be invoked -
1. Post/put/get Rest service with basic authentication over http protocol 
2. Post/put/get Rest service with basic authentication over Https protocol
3. Post/put/get services with different oauth authentication options, here one more call to get token is required.
4. Soap services with different authentication method.

The response processing logic also differs for different type of services.

As of now I have written separate methods for each of these, but this is not reusable as it's tightly coupled with type of service.

Can anyone suggests better design approach for this?

Comment: You could move the common logic into a single method, then call the new method with the common logic in each other method and only do specific stuff different auth and so on in each method after the common call

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract iteraction with API into separate service or services. For example `TaskApi` with `getTasks()`, `sendTask(Task task)`, etc. methods. Look at [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library, it much more convenient than using `HttpURLConnection` and helps you to solve authentication issues easy.

Comment: Thanks for retrofit library suggestion, but I can't use any library other than HttpURLConnection. Abstracting API interaction into separate service or method is similar to what I am already doing it right? Ex: if a Rest post/get/put API with oauth authentication needs to be invoked I have already created separate method which takes an object with all required details as input and invokes service. But again in this method already many if conditions I have added for response processing of different kind which makes code to look clumsy

Comment: It's hard say any without code. May be you should split code to different methods which process only one response variant. Or maybe api services may be organized somehow with strategy pattern for example.